# Pattern matching equality on tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, tuples, equality

For this function on symmetric equality over tuples,

```
symEq :: Eq a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool
symEq (x,y) (u,v) = (x,y) == (u,v) || (x,y) == (v,u)
```

would like to rewrite it using pattern matching as follows,

```
symEq' :: Eq a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool
symEq' (x,y) (x,y) = True
symEq' (x,y) (y,x) = True
symEq' _ _ = False
```

The latter fails with error on conflicting definitions for `x` and `y`. How to rewrite `symEq` and take benefit of pattern matching ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in some languages (I hear Erlang works that way), repeating a variable name in patterns in Haskell does *not* compare the values found at those two places, and is usually an error. So you are going to need to use `==` for that.

Anyway, here is a *slightly* more concise way of writing your function:

```
symEq t (x,y) = t == (x,y) || t == (y,x)
```

Or even

```
symEq t (x,y) = t `elem` [(x,y), (y,x)]
```

Comment: Indeed Erlang enables repeating of patterns to symbolize equality.

Answer (score 3):

With the `ViewPatterns` you can achieve something that resembles the Erlang and Prolog pattern matching style:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

swap (a,b) = (b,a)

symEq :: Eq a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool
symEq a ((==a) -> True) = True
symEq a ((==a).swap -> True) = True
symEq _ _ = False
```

Note how the `a` in `(==a)` refers to the first function argument - bound names of earlier function parameters may be used in the view patterns of later parameters.

More details on ViewPatterns may be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns).